# Why it does not display the text on the label of second window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner of python. In this code When I click the button "enter into", It opens a new window("second screen"). After then when I enter any text in the entry box, it should be print the text into a label. But it does not print.

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title("main")
root.geometry("300x300")

def call2():
    rt=Tk()
    rt.title("second screen")
    rt.geometry("400x400")
    a=StringVar()
    Entry(rt,textvariable=a).pack()
    def call3():
        b=a.get()
        Label(rt,text=b,bg="green").pack()
    Button(rt,text="print level",command=call3).pack()

Button(root,text="Enter into",font=15,command=call2).pack()
```

Comment: Never ever create multiple `Tk` instances.

Comment: So, what can I do, if I need multiple and individual windows ??

Comment: Use Toplevel instead.

Comment: You should have exactly one instance of `Tk`. If you need additional windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will try it.

Comment: Can you provide me an example code of TopLevel method???

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the second `Tk()` with `Toplevel()`. That is all you need to do to create a `Toplevel` instance, and it is where your problem lies. **Never create multiple `Tk()` instances**

Comment: @surajpal clicking the green tick next to an answer tells future people it is correct, awards you 2 rep and the answerer 15 rep.